Patching screw holes in Hardie Plank siding after rain storm
Speakers were attached to my house's exterior hardie plank siding long ago. I noticed yesterday evening that one of the speakers had separated from the wall (no idea how long it has been so), exposing holes in the siding. I want to remove the speakers and patch the holes today. However there was a heavy rain storm last night which surely pelted this area of the wall.
What prep should be done prior to caulking up the holes? Should I be worried about moisture that may have already gotten behind the siding? Is caulking the holes enough? Should I use exterior acrylic latex caulk?


Whatever moisture got in, is in.  Hopefully the house was prepped with house wrap and there was very little moisture that got in there.  Unless you want to tear off the siding to look , there isn't much you can do.
If the wall feels firm, caulk the holes with polyurethane sealant and paint when dry.
If the walls are soft or bouncy, you have a lot more work ahead of you.  Use screws imbedded in caulk to attach anything outside.
